# Что должно быть в конфигах api папке конфиг для того, чтоб в папке рантайм были логи?

Tags: yii2

Что должно быть в конфигах  api папке конфиг для того, чтоб в папке рантайм были логи?

Answer (score 0):

У меня так лог сохраняется в папке runtime/log файл app.log

```
 'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
```